# C#: Getting data from an access database and display it in a list box in

Tags: c#, ms-access

```
namespace Database_Project_Part_2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void displayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
                                    + "Data Source=C:\\Users\\dell\\Desktop\\Auto.mdb";

            //Create an OleDbConnection object, 
            //and then pass in the ConnectionString to the constructor.
            OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(connectString);

            //Open the connection.
            cn.Open();

            //Use a variable to hold the SQL statement.
            string selectString = "SELECT Manufacturer , Model, Y3ear, 
            Tranmission, Engine_Type, Drive_Train FROM Automobile;";

            //Create an OleDbCommand object.
            //Notice that this line passes in the SQL statement and the 
            //OleDbConnection object
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(selectString, cn);

            //Send the CommandText to the connection, and then build an 
            //OleDbDataReader.
            //Note: The OleDbDataReader is forward-only.
            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                automobileListBox.Items.Add(selectString);
                //Console.WriteLine(reader[0].ToString());
            }

            reader.Close();
            cn.Close();

        }

        private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know why I'm getting this error:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'No value given for one or more
>   required parameters.'  On line:  *OleDbDataReader reader =
>   cmd.ExecuteReader();*

since all of the syntax is correct.
Thank you,

Comment: The error message is usually given when some of your fields are mispelled. Please check the names given in the SELECT statement with the actual field names. By the way. To have a string splitted on two or more lines you need to prefix it with the verbatim character @ _@"SELECT .......";_

Comment: Y3ear, maybe a typo?

Comment: "Year" is a reserved word in access, so I used "Y3ear"

Comment: Got it figured out. Thank you!

Comment: Add your own answer and mark it correct (when you can). What was the problem?